# Failing to send JSON data using POST-method and HTTPS to Webserver with Java

Tags: java, json, post, https, webservice-client

Currently I'm trying to address a webserver using HTTPS and POST method and send a JSON file to this server. I have already tried several tutorials but unfortunately I can only find examples for HTTP and Post and not HTTPS. Did I forget to implement something?
I would like to provide the code of the server, but I only received the address and the format of the JSON files.

Has anyone had the problem before or can help me?
Thank you

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(" https://webservice.com:1234");
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    //con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    String jsonInputString = "\"ID\": \"12\"";

    System.out.println(jsonInputString);

    try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
        byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes("utf-8");
        os.write(input, 0, input.length);
        os.flush();
    }
    System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
```

Unfortunately I always get this error message:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or
>   unrecognized SSL message at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:439)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:184)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:108)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1180)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1091)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1362)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1337)
>     at
>   java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:247)
>     at test.main(test.java:40)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I noticed one whitespace on your `new URL(" https://webservice.com:1234");` is it a typo?

Comment: Just an copy-paste-error from the IDE, sorry.

Comment: May not be related to the problem, but your `String jsonInputString = "\"ID\": \"12\"";` is not a valid json. A valid json object should be something like `{"ID":"12"}`.

Comment: this is the autocompletion of IntelliJ. when I make a sysout of the JSON it is shown as "ID": "12". Additionally I have added the { } brackets around it. Unfortunately this does not change the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the https returns SSL errors if the service is not secure. This happens a lot in localhost or some servers with only http. Maybe try removing the 's'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I suppose you mean a connection via HttpURLConnection and the package java.net.HttpURLConnection? Like here:
`HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();`

Unfortunately, I still get the same mistake. Could it be due to another problem?

Comment: Oh, I was actually saying the actual string of the URL you're using, I have had that error many times in localhost servers and servers that have not HTTPS instead of having this: URL url = new URL(" https://webservice.com:1234"); change the URL to http://webservice.... but if you did that and the error persists then it's not that, it may be the server, also a comment there is right, you need to add these { } to your JSON to be valid, but I don't think invalid JSON returns SSL error

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all your help, in a discussion with the developer of the web service I was able realize that the server does not support HTTPS. That means the link to the server was wrong - `http//:` instead of `https//:`

So with the `HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();` it works just fine.